# Save a result from a loop to a list of variables

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to insert a group of similar entities and get id of each of them in one fell swoop. I'm trying this:

```
q1 = "question1"
q2 = "question2"
q3 = "question3"
q4 = "question4"

Enum.each([q1, q2, q3, q4], &(Repo.insert!(......)))

# working with q1 and id of q1
# .......


# working with q2 and id of q2
# .......

# and so on
```

Is there any way to, perhaps, create a second list of variables where I'd store the result-model returned by `Repo.insert`?
If not, then how would I access "id" of each inserted model: q1-q4?
Or should I instead insert them one-by-one instead and will it be easier and more straightforward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2):

```
ids = [q1, q2, q3, q4]
|> Enum.map(&Repo.insert!(......))
|> Enum.map(&Map.get(&1, :id))
```

---

You can also do this in steps:

```
structs = Enum.map([q1, q2, q3, q4], &Repo.insert!(......))
ids     = Enum.map(ids, &Map.get(&1, :id))
```

Comment: Why not? But if you prefer not to, you can use the same method to return a tuple with the inserted Struct along with the ids.

Comment: No reassigning. This is equivalent to: `ids = Enum.map([q1, q2, q3, q4], Enum.map(&Repo.insert!(......)), &Map.get(&1, :id))`

Comment: You can do this with a single call to `Enum.map/2` as well: `|> Enum.map(&Repo.insert!(......).id)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. One is to create a separate ID list and then iterate through both the lists using `Enum.zip/2`:

```
q1 = "question1"
q2 = "question2"
q3 = "question3"
q4 = "question4"

ids = Enum.map([q1, q2, q3, q4], &(Repo.insert!(......)))

for {q, id} <- Enum.zip([q1, q2, q3, q4], ids) do
  IO.inspect {q, id}
end
```

Another is to return the question/id pair from `Enum.map` (I'm using `for` here for some clearer code but you can use `Enum.map/2` as well):

```
pairs = for q <- [q1, q2, q3, q4] do
  {q, Repo.insert!(...)}
end
```

Then iterate similarly:

```
for {q, id} <- pairs do
  IO.inspect {q, id}
end
```